# Ideas on class Parameter structure given implementation

Tags: c++

Question simplified: an expression is a parameter. It includes 2 objects of type parameter. But, is that parameter a string_class, ID_class, or Expression_class parameter? If I just say Parameter, it won't have these certain characteristics, will it? How do I have these objects, use logic, and then I can know if the private data members of Expression are string, id, or expression parameters? Sometimes I want that left parameter to be an expression, sometimes I want it to be a string, sometimes an ID.

```
class Parameter
{
public:

private:

};

class String_class : public Parameter
{
    public:
        String_class(string in_string)


    private:
        string my_string;

};

class ID_class : public Parameter
{
    public:
        insert_id(string in_ID);

    private:
        string my_ID;

};


class Expression_class : public Parameter
{
private:
    Parameter left_parameter;
    Parameter right_parameter;
    string op;

public:

};
```

Comment: It's really hard to read your question. I recommend rephrasing or at least editing the post so it's easier to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I changed it for you

Comment: Are you looking for `std::any` or `std::variant`?

Comment: I think, possibly. I am not familiar. Can you give me an example?

Comment: If you wonder whether your `Parameter` is an `ID_class` (or something else), you can do `dynamic_cast<ID_class>(my_parameter)`. However, if your code too heavily relies on dynamic casts, your design is probably not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this...

```
enum ParameterType{
    PT_INVALID_TYPE = -1,
    PT_OPERATION_TYPE= 0,
    PT_STRING_TYPE,
    PT_ID_TYPE,
    PT_INT_TYPE,
    ...
    PT_MAX_TYPES
}

class Parameter {
    public:
    ...
    virtual ParameterType GetType() = 0;
    virtual string ToString() = 0; // GetValue(), etc...
}

class String_class : public Parameter
{
    public:
        String_class(string in_string){}

        virtual ParameterType GetType() override { return PT_STRING_TYPE; }
        virtual string ToString() override {return my_string;}; 


    private:
        string my_string;

};

class ID_class : public Parameter
{
    public:
        insert_id(string in_ID);

        virtual ParameterType GetType() override { return PT_ID_TYPE; }
        virtual string ToString() override {return my_ID;}; 

    private:
        string my_ID;

};

enum OperationType {
    OP_INVALID_OP = -1,
    OP_CONCATENATE = 0,
    OP_ADD,
    OP_COMPARE_EQUAL,
    OP_COMPARE_LESS_THAN,
    OP_XOR,
    ... // whatever
    OP_MAX,
}

class Expression_class : public Parameter
{
private:
    Parameter* left_parameter;
    Parameter* right_parameter;
    string op;

public:

};
```

Some usage examples...

```
class Expression_class : public Parameter
{
private:
    Parameter* left_parameter;
    Parameter* right_parameter;
    string op;

public:

    Expression_class(string _op, Parameter* lhs, Parameter* rhs):
    left_parameter(lhs), right_parameter(rhs), op(_op)
    {
        // alternatively
        left_parameter = lhs;
        right_parameter = rhs;
        op = _op;
    }

    ~Expression_class(){
        left_parameter = nullptr;
        right_parameter = nullptr;
    }

    virtual ParameterType GetType() { return PT_OPERATION_TYPE; };
    virtual string ToString() { return eval(); }

protected:
    string eval() { 

        if(left_parameter.GetType() != PT_ID_TYPE) return "Invalid left_parameter.";
        if(right_parameter.GetType() != PT_STRING_TYPE) return "Invalid right_parameter";

        switch(op){ // op is better as OperationType than string
            case OP_CONCATENATE : return left_parameter.ToString() + " " + right_parameter.ToString();
            // ...

        }

        if(CompareNoCase(op, "+") == 0) 
            return left_parameter.ToString() + " " + right_parameter.ToString();

        return "Invalid Opertaion";

    }
};


String_class employee_name("Rick");
String_Id    employee_id("007");

Expression_class exp(OP_CONCATENATE, &employee_id, employee_name);
return exp.ToString();
```

**Notes**  This is not the only way to do it, and as you use your class, you'll figure out short cuts to do less work.

Comment: What is the point of having a class hierarchy _and_ a `ParameterType`? Seems very redundant to me.

Comment: Because you can use the base class pointer and query the type/value without knowing the derived type.  This approach is slightly faster than the RTTI approach and avoids casts.

Comment: James Poag - That looks great, looks like something I need. Only one question, since I'm not the best at pointers. I will then need a function inside Expression class that assigns these left and right parameters. what is the syntax to, at implementation in this function, assign the left parameter, say, pointer as ACTUALLY an ID class object for instance?

Comment: Why do you have virtual methods returning constants instead of storing the constant? And why do you have a enum type for operators but store it as string?

Comment: Abstract Virtual methods form a sort of contract for any derived classes, a way for the compiler to complain that you haven't explicitly implemented a requirement.

Comment: Hold on, @Rick, I'll update with example of one way to do it.

Comment: If you neglected to initialize the constant, there will be compiler warnings too, using something that involves runtime performance for a reason that should be statically resolved seems weird

Comment: And btw, explain your code as opposed to just giving it

Comment: Passer By- While I understand your concerns, I feel like sometimes on stack overflow, we worry too much about "prettiness," and neglect too much the nitty gritty, directness of answering questions. This implementation is beautiful, understandable enough, and gives me far more ideas than I have seen so far.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're final usage is, but I would suggest looking up the shunting yard algorithm if you are doing simple expression parsing.  Also, you can check the types of the parameters to determine the meaning of the operation.  E.g. "+" on two strings concatenates them, whereas "+" for IDs or integers would add them.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!